# HTTP POST/GET requests are not working with Apigee proxy and AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, proxy, apigee

I have deployed my web site on Amazon EC2 instance and having mysql database installed on EC2 instance. I have used apigee as management tool and created the proxy for API which connect to my mysql DB through PHP. But when i am trying to send or receive data from DB through HTTP POST and GET, It is not working. Instead of calling PHP script as /localhost/.../abc.php I have used proxy that created through Apigee. Can anyboby tell me what i am doing wrong here. 
Note : When i am using localhost instead of proxy my code is working fine. 
 here is my HTTP requests using localhost and using Apigee proxy,

Using localhost :

```
    $http.get('http://localhost/MWS/abc.com/api.php?action=get_productdetails').
        success(function(data) {
                            $scope.products = data.returnop;
                });


$http.post('http://localhost/MWS/abc.com/api.php?action=get_orderdetails', 
                    {   'userid' : UserID
                    }).
        success(function(data) {
                                        $scope.orderdet = data.orderdetails;
                });
```

Using Apigee proxy :

```
$http.get('http://pmn1-test.apigee.net/apicall?action=get_productdetails').
        success(function(data) {
                            $scope.products = data.returnop;
                });


$http.post('http://pmn1-test.apigee.net/apicall?action=get_orderdetails', 
                    {   'userid' : UserID
                    }).
        success(function(data) {
                                        $scope.orderdet = data.orderdetails;
                });
```

Comment: This is dummy proxy.. I have checked with hitting this URL in browser and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please learn to print some error messages, meaningful error messages, when 'something' fails. Hopefully the writer of 'something' that is failing would have provided enough information in the error message for you to be able to figure out what is wrong. At least that is a starting point. You do not even have a HTTP layer error message (like timeout) OR HTTP return, like 500, printed.

Comment: Hi Amit, I am newbie and dont know how to set these error messages can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Hi, My proxy is working fine it returns me the JSON array and I am able to see the output returned from proxy but somehow my code is not able to pick that output and instead it goes to error part.